# Telegram Bot(ngrok) deploy to heroku

Tags: python, heroku, webhooks, telegram-bot

I have created a telegram bot using flask which works completely fine with ngrok but I want to deploy it to Heroku for lifetime use.

Below is my webhook function where I used this ngrok url but I want to use heroku url which fails.
Can anyone help  me?

```
@app.route("/setwebhook")
def setwebhook():   
    url = "https://f0b7-180-151-17-204.ngrok.io" 
    s = requests.get("https://api.telegram.org/bot{}/setwebhook?url={}".format(bot_token,url))

    if s:
        return "Connection established"
    else:
        return "Connection failed"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug="True")
```

Comment: Which error do you get in the logs? I think you miss the PORT, also the ngrok URL needs to be replaced with Heroku URL of your app. Is it a Flask app?

Comment: Ya its a flask app you ca checkout my ful code here https://github.com/kaniket7209/telegram-bot-using-ngrok--pep-nik-bot   and its working fine with ngrok but i dont understand why changing the url with heroku url the connection to telegramfails to establish but the app works...

Comment: can anyone help me to deploy this app to heroku using heroku url...link to my full code is here https://github.com/kaniket7209/telegram-bot-using-ngrok--pep-nik-bot

Answer (score 0):

On Heroku a Flask app should bind to the `$PORT`

```
p = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000))
app.run(debug=True, port=p, host='0.0.0.0')
```